# Crop multiple portion from one image

Tags: image, android-studio, opencv, android

[image: what I want to achieve]I have a image from which I need create multiple smaller images by drawing rectangles on the parent image, using opencv I know how to draw a rectangle and cut it from the image using `Mat` and `Rect`, but the main problem I am facing is that the image is entered through user input and the user can choose to select any portion he/she wants to crop out, so everything needs to be dynamically operated.
The attached image will clarify things a bit 
I am new to opencv with android so any help is appreciated.
also if one can provide solution without using opencv is also welcome.

Comment: Do you mean you want to capture mouse events? There's a tutorial here if that's what you want: [link](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/03/09/capturing-mouse-click-events-with-python-and-opencv/)

Comment: any idea on how to do it using android? @ShawnMathew